# Use character substitution in BibTeX .bst file

Tags: bibtex, doi

I use BibTeX not only to create bbl files for my LaTeX documents, but also to produce HTML of my whole collection of articles. It works pretty well for the last 12 years but since I decided to add a DOI field I've got a minor problem.

BibTeX, outputs

```
(<small>doi:<a href=http://dx.doi.org/10.1051/jp2:1995145>10.1051/jp2:1995145</a></small>)
```

as I programmed it like

```
FUNCTION {startdoienc}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { " (<small>doi:<a href=http://dx.doi.org/" swap$ * ">" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {enddoienc}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "</a></small>)" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  .... <cut out>
  new.block
  doi startdoienc  output
  doi enddoienc  pureoutput 
  new.block
  .... <cut out>
}
```

So the HTML result looks like

A. Ajdari, F. Brochard-Wyart, C. Gay, P. G. de Gennes, and J. L. Viovy **Drag on a tethered chain moving in a polymer melt** *J. Phys. II France* 1995 5 491–495 (doi:[10.1051/jp2:1995145](http://dx.doi.org/10.1051/jp2:1995145))

where the DOI link is clickable.

However, some journals (e.g. J. Polym. Sci. B: Polym. Phys.) have characters in their DOI's, which need to be escaped to become a valid URL: <, >, and #.
Example:

`10.1002/(SICI)1099-0488(19990701)37:13<1449::AID-POLB11>3.0.CO;2-T`

Question: is it possible to program BibTeX to substitute, e.g., "**<**" by "**%3c**" before outputting it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search-and-replace is possible using BibTeX. The excellent [*Tame the BeaST*](http://ctan.org/pkg/tamethebeast) suggests

```
INTEGERS{ l }
FUNCTION{ string.length }
{
  #1 'l :=
  {duplicate$ duplicate$ #1 l substring$ = not}
    {l #1 + 'l :=}
  while$
  pop$ l
}

STRINGS{replace find text}
INTEGERS{find_length}
FUNCTION{find.replace}
{ 'replace :=
  'find :=
  'text :=
  find string.length 'find_length :=
  ""
    { text empty$ not }
    { text #1 find_length substring$ find =
        {
          replace *
          text #1 find_length + global.max$ substring$ 'text :=
        }
        { text #1 #1 substring$ *
          text #2 global.max$ substring$ 'text :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}
```

So you should be able to do something like

```
FUNCTION {startdoienc}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    {
       " (<small>doi:<a href=http://dx.doi.org/" swap$ 
       "<" "\%3c" find.replace 
       * ">" *
    }
  if$
}
```

You may also need to escape the `%` to stop it being read as a comment by LaTeX.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! Just a small remark: I do not need to escape "%" in my particular case as I output HTML, not TeX.

Comment: After a bit more thorough testing I do run into a problem: the trick is okay with "<" and ">" but fails on "#". I tried using "\#" instead but it does not work either: bibtex does not complaint but does not substitute '#' by '%23'either.

Comment: @user7788: I suspect you may be out of luck, as `#` is 'special' for BibTeX, and I'm not sure this can be turned off.

Comment: I think I'm going to solve that '#'-issue with a simple perl script. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: huh, all I had to do to replace the `#` correctly was to do `url "#" "\#" find.replace`

Comment: perhaps it is because I wrapped the urls already in `\url{`